# referencing new Table as new_table not visible to the trigger function Postgresql

Tags: postgresql-11

I am new in Postgresql so this question may be dumb for you guys!
I am tring to use the referenced tables in a trigger function, but some how the function doesn't seem to have access on the referenced alias (`new_table`) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION Function_Name()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT tbl.some_field INTO new_table.other_field
    from some_table as tbl;
    return null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I am having this error:

```
"new_table.other_field" is not a known variable
```

---

and here is the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Name 
AFTER INSERT
ON Table_Name
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION Function_Name();
```

The function code should be executed first and then the trigger's, so how could the function access the alias that is referenced **later** in the trigger defenition??

and how to access the referenced table aliases in the function?

Note: In my example I am tring to use the alias, so when I use **NEW** inplace of **new_table** the function is created successfully!

Comment: yes you are right, if the some_table had a lot of data but it only has one row it is a parameter table, and actually the code didn't work even if I used a function like SELECT some_function() INTO new_table.other_field;

Comment: lets say that i am using limit 1 at the end, but i can't use the assignement directly notice that i am selecting the data from another table, may be i can declare a variable and save the data in it but that will be a lot of work for hundred of already written triggers with such a select statement

Comment: for the case where i use a function 
SELECT some_function() INTO new_table.other_field;
the assignement didn't work

Comment: so your first comment is wrong where you said:

just assign it: new_table.other_field := new_table.some_field;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i am tring to set data in the `NEW` table using the alias name, however to do that i should use the original name `NEW` and not the referenced alias `new_table`..

The referenced alias `new_table` could be used to only get data from, like in `FROM CLAUSE`, `joins` and `WHERE CLAUSE` where one doesn't change the data in the referenced table.

---

**Update:**

here is an example of what i did to test that:

```
create table test_table2(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
    )

create table test_table(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
    )

create or replace function F_test_table()
returns trigger as $$
begin
    insert into test_table2(id, name)
    select id, name from new_table;
    return null;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

drop trigger if exists tr_test_table ON test_table;
create trigger tr_test_table
AFTER INSERT
ON test_table
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
for each row    ------- row level trigger ---------
EXECUTE FUNCTION F_test_table();


insert into test_table
values(1, '11111')

select * from test_table2
```

notice that the trigger inserts the data into test_table2

Comment: The "referenced alias" is irrelevant for a row level trigger.

Comment: Nope, this time you are wrong, i don't mean to be rude but referenced alias just worked for me in a row level trigger and i am adding the example in the anaswer..try it your self man :)

Comment: That is strange, because [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-COMPATIBILITY) says: "*the row variables used in FOR EACH ROW triggers may not be specified in a REFERENCING clause (...) **but is fixed for any one language***"

Comment: I think that the behaviour you are talking about is still in the currently missing list as mentioned in the link you sent...